# Significato e uso di "impernacchiato"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adjectives, regional

Nel romanzo *Storia della bambina perduta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> *Tagliava la testa ai ritratti*, rideva Imma incredula, *faceva impiccare i ritratti*. E dopo quelle decapitazioni e impiccagioni Masaniello indossava un abito di seta azzurra ricamato d’argento, metteva al collo una catena d’oro, attaccava al cappello una spilla di diamanti e andava al Mercato. Ci andava così, mamma, tutto **impernacchiato** da marchese, duca e principe, lui che era plebeo, lui che era pescatore e non sapeva né leggere né scrivere.

La mia domanda è sul termine "impernacchiato", che non ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Dal contesto posso immaginare che significhi "vestito in modo elegante e ricercato". È così? Si tratta di un vocabolo di origine dialettale? Si usa solo in Campania?

Comment: Vedo qui che l'aggettivo è campano e significa "agghindato": https://books.google.it/books?id=fQzYBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT86&lpg=PT86&dq=impernacchiato+agghindato&source=bl&ots=OfDhleG-Kx&sig=n4UaHVL2NeSoLmOW7HBFnBztyhA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP8cun8o_UAhVIIMAKHT8TAbgQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=impernacchiato%20agghindato&f=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questo [interessante sito che spiega l'etimologia del termine dialettale napoletano ***pereta***](http://pereta.it/etimologia.php) ho trovato un altrettanto interessante passaggio che forse può rispondere alla tua domanda:

> Pernacchio deriva da "vernacchio", da "vernaculum": cosa popolare,
>   scurrile, dal sostantivo verna=schiavo nato nella casa dei padroni. La
>   v mutò poi in p, e il vernacchio in pernacchio. Prima di andare
>   avanti, una preghiera: non si confonda il pernacchio con la
>   pernacchia. "Pernacchia" non significa scorreggia, come (in origine)
>   il suo omologo maschile; ma nemmeno - come molti invece credono - vuol
>   dire emissione oltraggiosa di aria dalla bocca. La pernacchia è una
>   donna volgare, ma soprattutto "curiosa", nell'accezione napoletana del
>   termine: una donna ridicola che, non sapendo di esserlo, e pensando al
>   contrario di essere bella ed elegante, si agghinda in modo vistoso e
>   originale, credendo così di far colpo.

Quindi l'aggettivo ***impernacchiato/a*** (presente in molti dialetti del meridione, tipo il foggiano) indica una persona abbigliata con una ricercatezza tale che però ottiene esattamente il risultato opposto, cioè sembrare ridicola.

Answer (score 0):

Premesso che "pernacchia" è un termine derivante dal napoletano (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pernacchia/) che indica un suono derisorio (questo per intenderci: http://imalbum.aufeminin.com/album/D20130705/0_uplfrm_pernacchia_H161139_L.jpg), credo che in questo caso "impernacchiato" indichi sì che era vestito in modo elegante, ma è un'eleganza del tutto artificiosa ed esagerata con cui il personaggio si pavoneggia, e tale da suscitare ilarità. Forse possiamo dire "addobbato come un albero di Natale" o "impettito come un pavone" per rendere l'idea.

Comment: Scusa, ma non riesco a capire la relazione tra quello che spiega il Treccani su "pernacchia" e questo significato.

Comment: @Charo E' l'unico significato che mi è venuto in mente;
Ci ho dovuto pensare su un attimo.. e ora mi è venuta l'illuminazione (a scoppio ritardato) e credo che il termine in realtà non derivi -almeno direttamente - dalla "pernacchia" ma sia una storpiatura di "pennacchio" (piuma o insieme di piume che si mettono come vistosa decorazione sui berretti). Sono convinto che l'autrice usi in ogni caso il termine per indicare quanto  l'abbigliamento del personaggio fosse esageratamente vistoso, involontariamente ridicolo ed infine ottenesse l'effetto opposto a quello prefissato (sembrare elegante)